# Using "requests" (in ipython) to download pdf files

Tags: python, web-scraping, web, python-requests

I want to download all the pdf docs corresponding to a list of "API#" values from http://imaging.occeweb.com/imaging/UIC1012_1075.aspx

So far I have managed to post the "API#" request but not sure what to do next.

```
import requests
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
url = 'http://imaging.occeweb.com/imaging/UIC1012_1075.aspx'
API = '15335187'
payload = {'txtIndex7':'1','txtIndex2': API}
session = requests.Session()
res = session.post(url,headers=headers,data=payload)
```

Comment: Look at `res.content`. That URL returns a form. You need to figure out how fill out that form first (what values would you enter manually?). From there you start building a POST request to download each file.

Comment: use `lxml` or `BeautifulSoup` with `res.content` to parse it and then you can search tags in HTML and get informations.

Comment: it seems this page is generated with Microsoft DotNet so it sends many hidden elements - like `__VIEWSTATE` - which you have to send too. You can use `DevTool` in Chrome/Firefox to see all headers/parameters send from browser to server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import mechanicalsoup
import urllib

url = 'http://imaging.occeweb.com/imaging/UIC1012_1075.aspx'
Form = '1012'
API = '15335187'
browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser(
  user_agent='Mozilla/5.0'
)
browser.open(url)

# Fill-in the search form
browser.select_form('form#Form1')
browser["txtIndex7"] = Form
browser["txtIndex2"] = API
browser.submit_selected("Button1")

# Display the results
for tr in browser.get_current_page().select('table#DataGrid1 tr')[2:]:
  try:
    pdf_url = tr.select('td')[0].find('a').get('href')
  except:
    print('Pdf not found')
  else:
    pdf_id = tr.select('td')[0].text
    response = urllib.urlopen(pdf_url) # for python 2.7, for python 3. urllib.request.urlopen()
    pdf_str = "C:\\Data\\"+pdf_id+".pdf"
    file = open(pdf_str, 'wb')
    file.write(response.read())
    file.close()
    print('Pdf '+pdf_id+' saved')
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit more complicated than that, there are some additional event validation hidden input fields that you need to take into account. For that you first need to get the page, collect all the hidden values, set the value for the API and then make a POST request with following HTML parsing of the HTML response.

Fortunately, there is a tool called [`MechanicalSoup`](https://github.com/MechanicalSoup/MechanicalSoup) that may help to auto-fill these hidden fields in your the form submission request. Here is a complete solution including sample code for parsing the resulting table:

```
import mechanicalsoup


url = 'http://imaging.occeweb.com/imaging/UIC1012_1075.aspx'
API = '15335187'
browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser(
    user_agent='Mozilla/5.0'
)
browser.open(url)

# Fill-in the search form
browser.select_form('form#Form1')
browser["txtIndex2"] = API
browser.submit_selected("Button1")

# Display the results
for tr in browser.get_current_page().select('table#DataGrid1 tr'):
    print([td.get_text() for td in tr.find_all("td")])
```

Comment: Thank you @alecxe. Great help!
I still have to open each pdf and then download/save it somewhere locally. 
Can I add something like
>> file = open("document.pdf", 'w')
>> file.write(td.read())
>> file.close()
inside the loop?

Comment: if I have to be strict, even though the answer is indeed very helpful, the code does not output pdf files. And I am not skilled enough to figure out how to do that still.